# How to listen to the log out event to record the event on the database?

Tags: symfony4

When a user connects to the application, a listener detects the connection event and updates the `last_login_at` field for the user.

The problem appears when the user wants to log out.

When disconnected, the listener's `onSecurityAuthenticationSuccess` method is always called.

Problem once disconnected we can no longer recover a user (in the session)

What I would like is to be able to record the date of the last connection in the database called the `onSecurityAuthenticationSuccess` method only on login and not on login and logout.

In addition I have an `is_in_line` field in the database and I would like to disconnect, I can detect the event "disconnection" and update this field
How can I do this?

Here is my code to list it

```
public function onSecurityAuthenticationSuccess (AuthenticationEvent $ event) {
 
    $ user = $ event-> getAuthenticationToken () -> getUser ();
 
    if ($ user) {
     
        // dd ($ user);
        $ user-> setLastLoginAt (new \ Datetime ('now'));
 
        $ this-> em-> persist ($ user);
        $ this-> em-> flush ();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be careful on using `security.authentication.success` event that is why it is called every time when a user session is valid and authenticated successfully, of which means on every refresh or sub request you are updating your entity. This happens when you enable `always_authenticate_before_granting` for session based authentication.

You can use `security.interactive_login` instead. See [InteractiveLoginEvent](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.4/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Event/InteractiveLoginEvent.php)

When you need to update your entity on user logged out you can listen `security.logout_on_change` event. It provides original token which you can get user id or other properties of the token. See [DeauthenticatedEvent](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.4/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Event/DeauthenticatedEvent.php)

Example:

```php
public function onInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event): void
{
    $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();

    $this->updateUserLastLogin($user);
}


public function onDeauthenticated(DeauthenticatedEvent $event): void
{
    $user = $event->getOriginalToken()->getUser();

    $this->updateUserLastLogin($user);
}

private function updateUserLastLogin($user): void
{
    if ($user) {

        $user->setLastLoginAt(new \Datetime('now'));

        $this->em->persist($user);
        $this->em->flush();
    }
}
```